# Confusion in a trick in solving an energy eigenfunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, symmetry, hydrogen

Given a non-relativistic energy eigenfunction for a central potential $\left|\Phi \right>$

In solving relativistic hydrogen atom, one of the terms is

$$
\left<\Phi\middle|\frac{e^2}{r}\middle|\Phi\right> \tag{1}
$$

I have read a trick to solve it is:

$$
 \left<\Phi\middle|\frac{e^2}{r}\middle|\Phi\right>  =\left<\Phi\middle|\frac{-e}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial e}\left[\frac{\hat {P}^2}{2m}-\frac{e^2}{r}\right]\middle|\Phi\right> 
  =
\left<\Phi\middle|\frac{-e}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial e}\middle[\hat {H}\middle|\Phi\middle>\right]\tag{2}
$$

and it gives the correct value  $$-\frac{me^4}{\hbar^2n^2}  .\tag{3}$$

In order to understand this trick, I tried this in another term:

$$
\left<\Phi\middle|\frac{e^4}{r^2}\middle|\Phi\right> 
=\left<\Phi\middle|\frac{e^2}{r} \frac{e^2}{r}\middle|\Phi\right>
=\left<\Phi\middle|\frac{e^2}{4}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial e}\left(\frac{P^2}{2m}-\frac{e^2}{r}\right)\right]^2\middle|\Phi\right>
,\tag{4}
$$
assuming $(\frac{\partial}{\partial e}\hat{H})^\dagger = \frac{\partial}{\partial e}\hat{H}$.

then this equals

$$
\left<\frac{e}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial e} \left(\frac{\hat{P}^2}{2m}-\frac{e^2}{r}\right)\Phi\right|\left|\frac{e}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial e}\left(\frac{\hat{P}^2}{2m}-\frac{e^2}{r}\right)\Phi\right>
= \left(\frac{me^4}{\hbar^2n^2}\right)^2
.\tag{5}
$$
However, since this very term is supposed to tell us how the relativistic effect destroy the symmetry, while this result gives us no degeneracies breaking. As it turns out, the correct answer for this term is $$\frac{m^2e^4}{(\ell+1/2)\hbar^4n^3}.\tag{6}$$

It takes me so long that I still can't figure it out where is wrong, I suspect $\frac{\partial}{\partial e}\hat{H}$ is not Hermitian.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The theory behind the trick is based on the [Hellmann-Feynman (HF) theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmann%E2%80%93Feynman_theorem)
$$ \frac{dE_{\lambda}}{d\lambda}~=~\langle \psi_{\lambda} | \frac{d\hat{H}_{\lambda}}{d\lambda}|  \psi_{\lambda} \rangle,\tag{A}$$
which works with a single derivative, but not with a square of a derivative, cf. OP's failed calculation (5) for the expectation value $\langle\frac{1}{r^2}\rangle$. Incidentally on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmann%E2%80%93Feynman_theorem#Expectation_values), the correct result (6) for $\langle\frac{1}{r^2}\rangle$ is obtained via the HF theorem by varying wrt. the azimuthal quantum number $\ell$ rather than the electric charge $e$. (Concerning a subtlety in the variation wrt. $\ell$, see also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14780/2451) related Phys.SE post.)