# How to calculate $\langle 1/r^2 \rangle$ for hydrogen using Hellmann-Feynmann Theorem? Wikipedia is wrong, isn't it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I was taking a read at the [Hellmann-Feynmann Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmann%E2%80%93Feynman_theorem) on wikipedia. Basically, the theorem claims:

> **Theorem:** If $\hat H_\lambda$ is the Hamiltonian operator dependent on a continuous parameter $\lambda$, and $E_\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of the eigenstate $\psi_\lambda$, both of them depending on continuous parameter $\lambda$, then: 
>   $$
> \frac{dE_\lambda}{d\lambda} = 
> \bigg\langle\frac{d \hat H_\lambda}{d\lambda}\bigg\rangle = 
> \bigg\langle \psi_\lambda \bigg| \frac{d \hat H_\lambda}{d \lambda} \bigg| \psi_\lambda \bigg\rangle
> $$

Wikipedia also [proves the theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmann%E2%80%93Feynman_theorem#Proof). So far so good. But then, wikipedia seems to think one can use the theorem to compute $\langle 1/r^2 \rangle$ on the hydrogen atom. [And shows how](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmann%E2%80%93Feynman_theorem#Expectation_values). I disagree on his proof. Here is a copy paste of all relevant points in wiki's proof:

> $$
> \hat{H}_{l}=-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2\mu r^2}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r}\left(r^{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r}\right)-l(l+1)\right) -\frac{Ze^{2}}{r} \quad\implies\quad
> \frac{\partial \hat{H}_{l}}{\partial l} = \frac{\hbar^{2}}{2\mu r^{2}}(2l+1)
> $$ 
>   Then:
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \bigg\langle\psi_{nl}\bigg|\frac{1}{r^{2}}\bigg|\psi_{nl}\bigg\rangle &= \frac{2\mu}{\hbar^{2}}\frac{1}{2l+1}\bigg\langle\psi_{nl}\bigg|\frac{\partial \hat{H}_{l}}{\partial l}\bigg|\psi_{nl}\bigg\rangle \\
> &=\frac{2\mu}{\hbar^{2}}\frac{1}{2l+1}\frac{\partial E_{n}}{\partial l} \\
> &=\frac{2\mu}{\hbar^{2}}\frac{1}{2l+1}\frac{\partial E_{n}}{\partial n}\frac{\partial n}{\partial l} \\
> &=\frac{2\mu}{\hbar^{2}}\frac{1}{2l+1}\frac{Z^{2}\mu e^{4}}{\hbar^{2}n^{3}} \\
> &=\frac{Z^{2}\mu^{2}e^{4}}{\hbar^{4}n^{3}(l+1/2)}.
> \end{align}
> $$

Wiki chooses the angular quantum number $l$ as $\lambda = l$. First of all, $l$ is not a continuous parameter, its discrete. Though, we can all pretend its continuous. Second of all, eigenvalues of the eigenstates $E_n$ does not depend on $l$. Third of all, in the middle of the proof Wikipedia does:
$$
\frac{\partial E_n}{\partial l} = 
\frac{\partial E_n}{\partial n}\frac{\partial n}{\partial l} \neq 0
$$

What just happened there? How can $dn/dl$ be non-null, if both $n$ and $l$ are independent?

**What I am asking is:** is this proof correct? Ie, the wiki calculation of $\langle 1/r^2 \rangle$.

- If yes: why? Why is it correct in those three points?
- If no: Can one calculate $\langle 1/r^2 \rangle$ for hydrogen using the Hellmann-Feynmann Theorem? How?

Comment: $l$ is a continuous parameter which is, in practice, discrete (much like Energy).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14780/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Then I'll have to ask why is $n = n_r + l + 1$. (or what $n_r$ is).

Comment: That is explained in eq. (6) in of my [Phys.SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/18251/2451).